# How to use generic classes with Gson

Tags: java, generics, gson

I try to do something like this:

```
Poperty<Integer> prop;
JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) parser.parse(string);

if(jsonObject.get("type").equals("Integer")){
    prop = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, Property<Integer>.class);
}
else if{...}
```

Heres the problem: `Property<Integer>.class`.
Is there a possibility to pass a generic `.class` somehow?

Comment: Class objects respresent the compiled source file at runtime. Therefore these objects can not take a generic argument. They represent the class with type T. `Property.class` will give you the matching class object, but I do not know how that works out with Gson.

Comment: Yes I know, the code is just to clarify what I want to achieve. Non generic Property.class as argument would work, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, replace `Property<Integer>.class` with `new TypeToken<Property<Integer>>(){}.getType()`.

Just as you would do when deserializing a `List<Integer>`.

Comment: Funny how I answered the same question twice in 24 hours... :-)